# A subgroup in Group theory

Tags: group-theory

I am currently studying group theory, and its a quite new concept for me. 
When learning about subgroups, I bumped into something.

In a problem where one wants to show that some set A is a group, is it sufficient enough to show that that set (A) satisfies all axioms of being a subgroup of a group B?

i.e.

If we know for sure that B is a group, 
and we show that some set A satisfies all axioms of being a subgroup of a group B,
can we conclude that A is a group?

Comment: Suppose set B is a group and A is a subset of B. If A is a subgroup, then A is also a group. So, yes.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done easier. Let $G$ be a group and $U$ be a nonempty subset of $G$.
Then $U$ forms a subgroup of $G$ iff (1) for all $g,h\in U$, $gh\in U$, and (2) for each $g\in U$, $g^{-1}\in U$.

Then $U$ forms a subgroup of $G$ without checking the axioms point by point.

For instance, the unit element $e\in G$ lies in $U$, since $U$ is nonempty and so $U$ has an element $g$. Then $g^{-1}\in U$ by (2) and so by (1) $e= gg^{-1}\in U$.

Comment: I'm sure you know this but for the OP: We can also collapse it down to just one condition: $U$ is a subgroup of $G$ $\iff$ $\forall (a \in U) \forall (b \in U) ab^{-1} \in U$ (this is often said verbally as "the subset is closed under subtraction", because in additive notation $ab^{-1}$ is denoted as $a-b$. And when you will study rings, you will switch to the additive notation for groups)

Comment: Surely, the ''subgroup criterion''.

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

No, as associativity may not be satisfied within the set. Consider, for instance, the structure $(S,*)$, with $S=\{1,a,b\}$, and the following definition table for $*$:
$$
   \begin{matrix} 
    *  &  \bf1 & \bf{a} & \bf{b} \\
      \bf1 & 1 & a & b \\
     \bf{a} & a & 1 & b \\
     \bf{b} & b & a & 1
   \end{matrix} 
$$
This satisfies the conditions for being a subgroup (it is closed under * and inverses, and it is nonempty), except for the fact that it is not in a group. But $(S,*)$ is not a group, because associativity fails: $1=a(ba) \neq (ab)a=a$

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question.

Comment: The question reads: "...to show that some set A is a group, is it sufficient enough to show that that set (A) satisfies all axioms of being a subgroup of a group B...". I provide a counterexample to show that it is not enough. The structure (S,*) satisfies the conditions for a subgroup, but is not a group.

Comment: But if it's already a subset of a group with the same operation, it's automatically associative. We're not talking about an arbitrary operation.

Comment: To quote the question, "If we know for sure that B is a group, and we show that some set A satisfies all axioms of being a subgroup of a group B, can we conclude that A is a group?"

Comment: I am not assuming that is a subset of a group. Maybe I missed the question.

Comment: So maybe part 1 and part 2 of the question can be interpreted differently. Now that you mention it, the question is not very clear to me. I focused on the first statement, not the second one.

Comment: I see how you could interpret it your way, actually. It's only implied that $A$ is a subset of $B$. But one could say that it's "common sense."

Comment: When interpreted "my way", is a cool question, I find.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is a group and $H\subseteq G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff it is nonvoid and closed under multiplication and inversion.  You do not need to verify all of the axioms in this case because much is inherited from $G$.