# Proving a subgroup / group - steps?

Tags: group-theory

This is not an exact exercise but more a question on how to solve exercises like showing something is a group or subgroup. (Could also be a ring or monoid)

I have some trouble finding out what exactly I have to show. I had an exercise where proving a subset is a subgroup meant showing that the subset contains the neutral element, admits an inverse and is closed under composition (that was in the description).

Now in a different exercise involving bilinear forms and then also proving that it is a Group, I had to show that it was associative, contained the neutral element and admitted an inverse.

The inverse and neutral element are clear. My question now is: How can I know when I have to prove that it is also associative or if it is closed? This would mean that the steps for showing that a subgroup is a group aren't always the same? Can this be?

Comment: You only need to show the subgroup axioms. That's much less. For example, for a subset of matrices of the group $GL_n(K)$, you don't have to show associativity and so on. So again, check the subgroup axioms carefully, what they are.

Comment: Well, if $(G, \cdot)$ is a group (semigroup also works) and $A \subseteq G$ is any subset of $G$, then $\cdot$ is associative on $A$. Think about why this is true. By the way, you should carefully read the definitions every time you want to prove a statement

Comment: @DietrichBurde So it should be stated in the exercise what the axioms of said group are and then only have to prove them?

Comment: @RickDoesMath I see. Well I think I just have to read the exercise carefully for it to make sure I'm not trying to prove things I shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, a subset $H$ in a group $G$ is a subgroup if and only if the subgroup axioms are satisfied. Read the answer by Wüstenfuchs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062766/a-subgroup-in-group-theory), or look them up in your algebra book. That's much less work than checking all group axioms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a two step test if $H$ is a subset of $(G,\cdot)$, $H$ is a subgroup iff:

1. $H$ is nonempty.
2. For any $x,y$ in $H$, we have that $x \cdot y^{-1} \in H$.

From this, all other group axioms can be derived.

In the usual order.

1. We inherit associativity from $G$. This is because we have the same binary operation and any element of $H$ must be an element of $G$. If association failed, we would have that it fails in $G$ also and so $G$ wasn't a group in the first place.
2. $H$ is nonempty by 1. so let $x \in H$. Then by 2. $x \cdot x^{-1}=1 \in H$. So the unit is in $H$.
3. The existence of the inverse follows by 2., letting x=1 for arbitrary $y$.
4. All of the above is enough to show closure. For all $x$,$x' \in H$ let us choose in 2. $x=x,y=(x')^{-1}$.